# Sourcing variables from a script file without executing code from that file

Tags: bash, shell-script, security

There are cases where a (Bash) script will need to import shell variables from another (untrusted?) script file.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
. /etc/lsb-release
#
#... make use of the contents of variable DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION
#
```

In cases like this, the file (`/etc/lsb-release` in the example above) may contain some (malicious or irrelevant) code that I would not like to be executed. I would only want to "import" the variable definitions in that file, but not execute any code in the file.

Is there a recommended method to do this, except something like `. <(grep = /etc/lsb-release)`?

Please, note that the file `/etc/lsb-release` is given as an example. The real question is how to import *only* variable definitions from a file and do *not* execute any code from that file.

Comment: You can't. Consider that the file might contain assignments like `PATH=/tmp/my_bad_stuff:$PATH`, where the dir contains malicious versions of, well, whatever. And someone might legitimately have assigments that rely on command substitutions, e.g. `FOO=$(echo "$BAR" | sed ...)` (regardless of if that's a good way to do it or not.)

Comment: If you want variables as data for use by the script itself, you might be better off loading them to an associative array. And then using e.g. `"${vars[DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION]}"` instead of `"$DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION"` in the script. Though `/etc/lsb-release` is likely not writable by just anyone (it's owned by `root:root` where I've seen it), so if someone can put malicious stuff there, they can probably just edit your script too

Comment: @muru You are right that the question is similar to mine. However, it seems that there is no _simple_ answer to this question. Thanks anyway! :)